# Reading of hex file in testbench : Verilog

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I have converted an image file into hex file which has R,G,B and alpha values in multiple columns. For example :

3c 48 36 ff 1d 2b 19 ff 08 18 06 ff 08 17 05 ff 14 1f 0d ff 1b 22 11 ff 1a 1f 0e ff 1a 1b 0b ff 1d 1a 0b ff 20 1a 0b ff 23 1a 0c ff 23 1c 0d ff 24 1d 0e ff 24 1d 0e ff 21 1c 0d ff 23 1c 0d ff 1f 1a 0b ff 1e 19 0a ff 1c 19 0a ff 1e 1a 0b ff 20 1a 0b ff 24 18 0b ff 23 18 0a ff 21 18 0a ff

Now I want a way to read and store this data as a collection of 32 bits( i.e. 4bytes). If I do not know how bytes are present in the file (since file can be of any size), how can I achieve this?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. Each pair of characters is the value in Hex so after the fourth pair (FF) you start your next set of values.

Comment: Verilog offers file I/O function like 'open', 'read', 'write' and 'close'. The read function for hexadecimal inputs should be your new friend: $readmemh(...) [Verilog file I/O reference](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00016.htm)

Comment: Hi, Can $fread be used to read hex files? or is it only for reading binary data?